# Theme taxonomy term page based on depth

Tags: views, theming, taxonomy-terms

Is there any solution on how theme the taxonomy term page per depth? Though this is doable with Views + TVI, we don't usually allow admin to manage TVI, but they're able to add new term and they're allowed to rearrange the terms. I would like that each depth has a different layout, but automatically changing based from its depth. This can done through hooks or how to achieve this in views?

For instance:

```
if ($depth == 0) {
  print $views_0;
}
elseif ($depth == 1) {
  print $views_1;
}
elseif ($depth == 2) {
  print $views_2;
}
else {
  print $views_default;
}
```

and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a funtion to retrive term depth

```
//Gets the depth of the term id
function MYMODULE_term_depth($tid) {
  $parent = db_query("SELECT parent FROM {taxonomy_term_hierarchy} WHERE tid = :tid", array(':tid' => $tid))->fetchField();
  if($parent == 0) {
    return 1;
  }else  {
    return 1+MYMODULE_term_depth($parent);
  }
}
```

And Print the views based on depth

```
$depth = MYMODULE_term_depth($tid)
if ($depth == 0) {
  print views_embed_view('views_0');
}
elseif ($depth == 1) {
  print views_embed_view('views_1');
}
elseif ($depth == 2) {
  print views_embed_view('views_2');
}
else {
  print views_embed_view('views_default');
}
```

pass the view machine name to `views_embed_view`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. Looks like this is what I need. I'll give it a try and will comment later. Thank you.

Comment: Hi cmsbots.com, I've made a test and check each terms $depth, I'm just confused why the parent term value is 2 and the second level value is 1, while the third level and the following level gives correct value.

Comment: Ooppss. My mistake. I have used the wrong tid. Everything works fine. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to use [`taxonomy_get_parents_all()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21taxonomy%21taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_get_parents_all/7):

```
$depth = count(taxonomy_get_parents_all($tid));
```